# Как избежать размытости изображений?

Tags: android, изображения

Хочу получить большую чёткость. Картинки, хорошо отрисованные в фотошопе размываются, когда я делаю из какой-нибудь например бекграунд для кнопки. Как этого можно избежать? Как сохранить чёткость?

Comment: * использовать 9patch
* отрисовать для каждого разрешения свой бэкграунд.

Comment: использую 9patch

Comment: А пример можно показать?

Comment: Можно еще в векторе их рисовать

Answer (score 1):

да я кажется разобралась. видимо, действительно для каждого разрешения необходимо рисовать свой бекграунд) т.к. на гелакси эйс одно и тоже приложение чётче, чем на гелакси эс2.